# AppInstallerPythonRedirector.exe has stopped working when installing emscripten

Tags: emscripten

I am trying to install emscripten using this guide: [Download and install — Emscripten 1.39.4 documentation](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html)

I ran the command:

```
emsdk>.\emsdk.bat install latest
```

The result is this error:

[image]

I have no idea what to do about it. I do have python and the error looks like segfault or uncaught exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this was quite an ugly problem. Turns out Windows had a "fake" python.exe somewhere in Windows Apps, possibly with the intention to ask you to install it. Why that didn't work, I don't know. But the correct solution was to install python from the official python website and update windows environment path appropriately.